# Cannot add the item to shopping cart. Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, stack-trace, magento-1.7

I've recently upgraded my Magento store from 1.4.2 to 1.7.0.2.
Now when I try to add products to the cart it displays the following error:

**Cannot add the item to shopping cart.**

Here's the stack trace:

```
2012-11-23T12:26:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::prepareCustomOptions(Array
(
)
)
Trace: #0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('prepareCustomOp...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php(357): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->prepareCustomOptions()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php(294): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract->_prepareProduct(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php(410): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped->_prepareProduct(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(901): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract->prepareForCartAdvanced(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(978): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProductAdvanced(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object), 'full')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(271): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(193): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/MW/Developertoolbar/Controller/Router/Standard.php(42): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): MW_Developertoolbar_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
2012-11-23T12:26:33+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::prepareCustomOptions(Array
(
)
)' in /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Object.php:652
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('prepareCustomOp...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php(357): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->prepareCustomOptions()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php(294): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract->_prepareProduct(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php(410): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped->_prepareProduct(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(901): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract->prepareForCartAdvanced(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(978): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProductAdvanced(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object), 'full')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(271): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(193): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/MW/Developertoolbar/Controller/Router/Standard.php(42): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): MW_Developertoolbar_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

I'm trying to add simple products to the cart if that helps.

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: How did you upgrade? Magento Connect or manually? It looks like some files didn't get moved over properly. Was there any upgrade errors?

Comment: I upgraded using this guide: http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/

There were a lot of errors at the final step, in which you visit the store and magento starts upgrading the database. I solved it by removing all the foreign keys for the database using a script, which was causing the errors. Then I ran the Magento Database Repair tool to set all the foreign keys again.

Comment: Can you look at the app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php and see if the `prepareCustomOptions()` function exists? I double-checked my repo of 1.7, and it is there. I am wondering if that file didn't get copied correctly.

Comment: It does exist on line 1974.

    public function prepareCustomOptions()
    {
        foreach ($this->getCustomOptions() as $option) {
            if (!is_object($option->getProduct()) || $option->getId()) {
                $this->addCustomOption($option->getCode(), $option->getValue());
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

Comment: Is there any caching on the server (APC)? I would kind of suspect that could be causing the issue.

Comment: There is on the production server. Memcached. Not on the development server though, where this error is occurring.

Comment: Without looking at it/debugging it myself, I'm kind of out of ideas.

Comment: Yea I know the feeling. :)

I'm trying to hunt it down. I thought that maybe it was one of the template files I created that was causing this issue, so I changed the template of the store to "Default".

I created two products, one simple, one grouped. Associated the simple product to the group product.

Now when I access that product on the frontend I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getSuperGroup() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/medicalemcasa.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Grouped.php on line 50

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any observer in your code or maybe a new extension you added that fires when you add item to a card, please find my below code that i fixed to solve the problem

Original:

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
$item->setMerchant($product->getMethant());
$item->save();
```

Solution:

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$quoteItem->setCustomAttribute($product->getCustomAttribute());
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I tried to understand what was throwing that error but to no avail.

So I solved it by installing a fresh installation of Magento 1.7 and upgraded my magento store from there.